# Changing app orientation not on the main activity

Tags: android

I am doing so by using this code in my Manifest file

`<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>`

But error message appears that the app failed to run tasks, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have 2 activities in my program, and the main one is defined in the manifest as so:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want to force my 2nd activity to always be in portrait mode. I was doing that by the code shown earlier. Yet my program won't compile, because it can't run tasks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific

Comment: @John Hope I made it more clear